# To create a new column with Pandas on the basis of two types of column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a  data frame `df`. The below table only represent top 8 rows of the data frame. There are multiple combination of `LIBRARY_NAME` and `ANCHOR_NAME`

```
BARCODE ANCHOR_NAME     LIBRARY_NAME    ANCHOR_CONC Synergy HSA     Bliss
14482   5-Fluorouracil  Cisplatin       2.5         FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
                                        10          FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
                        Docetaxel       2.5         FALSE   TRUE    TRUE
                                        10          FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
        AZD7762         Cisplatin       0.0625      TRUE    TRUE    TRUE
                                        0.25        FALSE   TRUE    TRUE
                        Docetaxel       0.0625      FALSE   FALSE   FALSE
                                        0.25        FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
```

I want to create a new column 'new_synergy 'with pandas which is based on column `ANCHOR_CONC` and `Synergy`. There are two ANCHOR_CONC for each anchor_name and library_name combination. If for any concentration of ANCHOR_CONC the synergy is `TRUE`, for other concentration also synergy becomes `TRUE`

Eg: `new_synergy`: Condition for TRUE (for AZD7762 and Cisplatin), IF at 0.0625 `Synergy` is TRUE, it will be TRUE for 0.25 also.

`Expected data_frame`

`new_df`

```
BARCODE ANCHOR_NAME     LIBRARY_NAME    ANCHOR_CONC Synergy HSA     Bliss  new_synergy
14482   5-Fluorouracil  Cisplatin       2.5         FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    FALSE
                                        10          FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    FALSE
                        Docetaxel       2.5         FALSE   TRUE    TRUE     FALSE  
                                        10          FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    FALSE
        AZD7762         Cisplatin       0.0625      TRUE    TRUE    TRUE     TRUE
                                        0.25        FALSE   TRUE    TRUE     TRUE
                        Docetaxel       0.0625      FALSE   FALSE   FALSE    FALSE
                                        0.25        FALSE   TRUE    FALSE    FALSE
```

I tried the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dd = data[["BARCODE", "LIBRARY_NAME", "ANCHOR_NAME", "ANCHOR_CONC", "Synergy", "Bliss", "HSA"]]
df = pd.pivot_table(data=dd,index=["BARCODE", "ANCHOR_NAME", "LIBRARY_NAME", "ANCHOR_CONC"])
## setting conditions as pivot table step converted true to 1 and false to 0. 
conditions = [(dd['Synergy'] == 1.0), (dd['Synergy'] == 0.0)]
values = ['True', 'False']
dd['new_synergy'] = np.select(conditions, values)
## However it is giving me the same results in both new_synergy and synergy column. I have no idea how to fit `ANCHOR_CONC` condition in this step.
```

Comment: Could you supply your code please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) as following :

`dd["new_synergy"] = dd[["ANCHOR_NAME", "LIBRARY_NAME", "Synergy"]].groupby(by=["ANCHOR_NAME", "LIBRARY_NAME"]).any()`

Explenation : you want to group your dataframe by both `ANCHOR_NAME` and `LIBRARY_NAME`, and return True if any of the `synergy`value is true, which is what `any()` does.

Note : you can check for all methods available for `GroupBy` objects [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html).

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on [this answer](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/19130/292), here is a full working example where I assume that `"BARCODE"`, `"ANCHOR_NAME"` and `"LIBRARY_NAME"` are used as `MultiIndex`:

Creating the test data:

```python
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
data_str = """BARCODE\tANCHOR_NAME\tLIBRARY_NAME\tANCHOR_CONC\tSynergy\tHSA\tBliss
14482\t5-Fluorouracil\tCisplatin\t2.5\tFALSE\tFALSE\tFALSE
14482\t5-Fluorouracil\tCisplatin\t10\tFALSE\tFALSE\tFALSE
14482\t5-Fluorouracil\tDocetaxel\t2.5\tFALSE\tTRUE\tTRUE
14482\t5-Fluorouracil\tDocetaxel\t10\tFALSE\tFALSE\tFALSE
14482\tAZD7762\tCisplatin\t0.0625\tTRUE\tTRUE\tTRUE
14482\tAZD7762\tCisplatin\t0.25\tFALSE\tTRUE\tTRUE
14482\tAZD7762\tDocetaxel\t0.0625\tFALSE\tFALSE\tFALSE
14482\tAZD7762\tDocetaxel\t0.25\tFALSE\tTRUE\tFALSE
"""
# StringIO is to simulate an import from a file
data = pd.read_table(StringIO(data_str), sep="\t", index_col=[0, 1, 2])
# reset_index is here just for displaying purposes
# (MultiIndex does not seem well supported in (pandas?) markdown export)
print(data.reset_index().to_markdown(index=False))
```

| BARCODE | ANCHOR_NAME | LIBRARY_NAME | ANCHOR_CONC | Synergy | HSA | Bliss |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14482 | 5-Fluorouracil | Cisplatin | 2.5 | False | False | False |
| 14482 | 5-Fluorouracil | Cisplatin | 10 | False | False | False |
| 14482 | 5-Fluorouracil | Docetaxel | 2.5 | False | True | True |
| 14482 | 5-Fluorouracil | Docetaxel | 10 | False | False | False |
| 14482 | AZD7762 | Cisplatin | 0.0625 | True | True | True |
| 14482 | AZD7762 | Cisplatin | 0.25 | False | True | True |
| 14482 | AZD7762 | Docetaxel | 0.0625 | False | False | False |
| 14482 | AZD7762 | Docetaxel | 0.25 | False | True | False |

Creating a `DataFrame` with the new column:

```python
new_synergy = data.reset_index().groupby(
    ["BARCODE", "ANCHOR_NAME", "LIBRARY_NAME"])[["Synergy"]].any()
# Rename the resulting "Synergy" column
new_synergy.columns = ["new_synergy"]
print(new_synergy.reset_index().to_markdown(index=False))
```

| BARCODE | ANCHOR_NAME | LIBRARY_NAME | new_synergy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14482 | 5-Fluorouracil | Cisplatin | False |
| 14482 | 5-Fluorouracil | Docetaxel | False |
| 14482 | AZD7762 | Cisplatin | True |
| 14482 | AZD7762 | Docetaxel | False |

Merging the two `DataFrame`s based on their indices:

```python
new_data = data.merge(new_synergy, left_index=True, right_index=True)
print(new_data.reset_index().to_markdown(index=False))
```

| BARCODE | ANCHOR_NAME | LIBRARY_NAME | ANCHOR_CONC | Synergy | HSA | Bliss | new_synergy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14482 | 5-Fluorouracil | Cisplatin | 2.5 | False | False | False | False |
| 14482 | 5-Fluorouracil | Cisplatin | 10 | False | False | False | False |
| 14482 | 5-Fluorouracil | Docetaxel | 2.5 | False | True | True | False |
| 14482 | 5-Fluorouracil | Docetaxel | 10 | False | False | False | False |
| 14482 | AZD7762 | Cisplatin | 0.0625 | True | True | True | True |
| 14482 | AZD7762 | Cisplatin | 0.25 | False | True | True | True |
| 14482 | AZD7762 | Docetaxel | 0.0625 | False | False | False | False |
| 14482 | AZD7762 | Docetaxel | 0.25 | False | True | False | False |